Gentoo Linux halted at boot, (udev-worker, stack depth)
the PC running Gentoo Linux was working fine until yesterday. Today he begins the boot checkup until he arrives at:
[   ok   ] Reached target multi-user.target.
[   ok   ] Reached target graphical.target.
[   17.218749] (udev-worker) (293) used greatest stack depth: 12504 bytes left 

And then it halts. Here is a photo of the full screen when this happens:

this seems to be a problem with udev-worker using all the memory available to it, does this means that I should free more disk memory for the system or for the swap partition?
Any answers that do not involve formatting the system and installing Gentoo (or some other distro) are welcomed ( I really want to leave formatting this PC as a last resort.).

If you press Ctrl + Alt + F2, do you have a login prompt showing?

Have you updated your kernel lately?  If so, did you rebuild your display drivers (i.e., maybe you missed a emerge @module-rebuild?)

@eyoung100 yes, I can access the system with a text environment, the login prompt appears and after making my login the following message appears: [13446.915610] systemd-journald[261]: File /var/log/journal/91a86c7d036649eaa9a8ab681452cdc5/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.

I don`t think I have updated my kernel in quite some time @Andy Dalton , I did run a general update on the installed packages of my system, but not on the kernel itsel.

The systemd message is just a warning that your log is being updated and replaced.  This may take me a minute, but as root issue systemctl stop xdm && systemctl disable xdm.  We can reenable the service after we finish troubleshooting.  After disabling them issue a reboot and let me know if the error still appears.

@eyoung100 I tried running systemctl stop xdm && systemctl disable xdm as root, but I recieved the following message "Failed to stop xdm.service: Unit xdm.service not loaded." So I don't think the problem is in xdm.

@eyoung100 I am running KDE.

If you followed The gentoo Wiki, which reccomends SDDM try systemctl stop sddm && systemctl disable sddm.service and reboot  I've deleted some of my previous comments as I had gorgotten about the Wiki.

I was sick yesterday so I couldn`t try those commands, I have tried them today and now I am booting into terminal text mode, how do I make the KDE environment work again from here on @eyoung100 ?

Did the boot error appear after you rebooted into text mode?

The udev-worker error appeared again.

Also a message that also appeared sometimes, also appearead now, kworker/dying (62) used greatest stack depth: 11584 bytes left.

kworker is short for kernel worker.  What is your kernel version?

@eyoung100 My kernel version is 6.1.19-gentoo.

Any Swap Partition? How much RAM?

Yes, I do have a swap partition of 10.5 Gb and 4 Gb of RAM. @eyoung100

Did you ever get this fixed?

Troubleshooting
This has been "open" awhile, so I'm going to attempt an answer with the following steps:

Update the portage tree: emerge --sync
Modify the USE Flags: nano -w /etc/portage/make.conf

Add -symlink to the USE= section


Update the kernel sources: emerge gentoo-sources

As of this answer, the current stable kernel version is: 6.6.62
This updates the kernel sources but no building takes place.


Set the kernel symlink manually: `uname -a && eselect kernel set 

This ensures any modules rebuilt in the next step are compiled and installed against the currently running kernel


Update the system as of the current portage tree: emerge -uDavN --with-bdeps=yes @world

Clear any backtracks/circular dependencies etc.



Build New Kernel

After the system update completes use eselect kernel again to set the kernel to the sources that were downloaded in step 3 above.
Read Gentoo Wiki: Kernel/Upgrade, and choose the desired upgrade method.

Pay attention to Section 4 to copy over and use the current running kernel to build the new kernel.



Answer via comment whether this resolved the issue.
